# Gtk Combobox select multiple options

Tags: python, gtk

I'm using Python with GTK, and I need to select more than one option in the ComboBox widget, but after searching the documentation, apparently it is not possible.

Does anyone know what I can do this?

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

When you don't know which widget can get the work done, give a look at the [widget gallery of the GTK+ documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch03.html). From the screenshots, [GtkListBox](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkListBox.html) looks like a good candidate for what you want to do, as you can have checkboxes for each item, meaning you can have multiple selection.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone needing multiple selection with GTK 2 specifically, you can refer to the answer I wrote on a different post [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62478083/7851115).

The idea is to use a `TreeView` and change its associated `TreeSelection`:

```
tree_view.get_selection().set_mode(gtk.SELECTION_MULTIPLE)
```

and it looks like this ([full MWE here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62478083/7851115)):

[image: A user interface with a list showing multiple elements selected]