# How do I make a GTK 2 list with multiple selection?

Tags: python, listbox, pygtk, gtk2

In a GTK 3 release, the `ListBox` widget added supported for [multiple elements being selected from the list](https://web.archive.org/web/20160604000132/http://worldofgnome.org/gtk-3-13-introduces-multi-selection-api-in-listbox/):

[image]

I'd like to achieve the same effect with GTK 2. I'm considering using a `ScrolledWindow` with a `VBox` of `CheckButton`'s. I fear it's not going to look very good though; [like this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pygtk/pygtk_checkbutton_class.htm), but with a scrollbar:

[image]

Does anyone know a good way to emulate the functionality in the first image using GTK 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there was a method of doing just this [buried in the documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtktreeview.html#method-gtktreeview--get-selection)! In fact, you should find it [all the way back to GTK 2.0](https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/commit/3ff4a2c081e5225f010ecaed91b162eabbb9caf5#diff-e3aaf78ccfaad52cc5a9a72696ef54ef), but the selection constant might have had a different name (`SELECTION_MULTI`).

The widget looks like this:

[image: A user interface with a list showing multiple elements selected]

The color scheme is inherited from my GNOME theme, so don't mind the window styling too much. This widget works with both `Ctrl` and `Shift` keys. It doesn't automatically have multiple selection just clicking on the different items.

Here's the (Python 2) MWE I made for this:

```
import gtk


class UI(gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        self.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
        self.set_default_size(250, 150)

        store = gtk.ListStore(str)
        for i in range(7):
            # The list notation here is odd, but required.
            store.append(["Item %d" % i])

        tree_view = gtk.TreeView()
        tree_view.set_model(store)

        # The view can support a whole tree, but we want just a list.
        renderer = gtk.CellRendererText()
        column = gtk.TreeViewColumn("Multiple Selection", renderer, text=0)
        tree_view.append_column(column)

        # This is the part that enables multiple selection.
        tree_view.get_selection().set_mode(gtk.SELECTION_MULTIPLE)

        scrolled_tree = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        scrolled_tree.set_policy(gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC, gtk.POLICY_ALWAYS)
        scrolled_tree.add_with_viewport(tree_view)

        self.add(scrolled_tree)


def main():
    win = UI()
    win.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
    win.show_all()
    gtk.main()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```